# Dice roller in Ruby (mainly for D&D)

Tags: ruby, random, dice

I have been working with Ruby for about a week or two now, and I wanted to create a dice-rolling application that intakes any string (e.g. 1d4 + 1 or 3d20 + 4) and outputs the correct dice rolling.

```
def roll(amount = 0, sides = 0)
    #this is the function that gets a random roll with the amount of sides and the amount of dice inputted.
    srand
    total = 0
    (amount.to_i).times do 
        total += rand(1..sides.to_i)
    end
    return total
end

while true
    raw_input = gets.chomp.to_s
    if raw_input == "exit"
        abort("May your rolls be ever natural.")
    end
    proc_input = raw_input.tr("^0-9", " ")
    #this keeps all the numbers from the string input. 
    output = proc_input.split()
    if (output[2]) == nil 
        mod = 0
    else 
        mod = output[2]
    end
    fin = roll(output[0], output[1]) + mod.to_i
    puts "#{fin.to_s}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice code overall, pretty readable, though there is space for improvements.

1) [You don't have to return](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-explicit-return) from ruby methods.

2) Good use of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html) methods will make code cleaner.

3) Use [`loop`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#infinite-loop) instead of `while true`

4) Also consider keyword arguments, as calling `roll(2, 4)` looks kind of cryptic.

Will all that in mind, we can turn your code into something like:

```
def roll(amount = 0, sides = 0)
  # rand(1..0) will return nil btw
  amount.to_i.times.sum { |t| rand(1..sides.to_i) }
end

loop do
  input = gets.chomp.to_s

  abort("May your rolls be ever natural.") if input == "exit"

  amount, sides, mod = input.tr("^0-9", " ").split
  fin = roll(amount, sides) + mod.to_i # nil converts to 0

  puts fin
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked back at the code, and some of my past projects and realized that I had written it like C or Java, instead of using a more powerful language's syntax and rules. Thanks again.